# Set Slack reminder for every 4 weeks

Tags: slack

Is it possible to set a slack reminder for every 4 weeks? I've tried `/remind me test at 3pm on Tuesday every 4 weeks` but the reminder is set for every 2 weeks.

Thanks for any hints!

Answer (score 24):

Try placing your reminder text in double quotes and specifying a start date like so:

```
/remind me "test" every 4 weeks starting October 23rd at 3PM
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: As of May 2020, this doesn't work anymore: `I will remind you “test” at 3PM every 4 weeks (next occurrence is Friday, June 5th).`

Comment: I just tested with `/remind me "test" every 4 weeks starting May 29th at 11:30AM` - Slack responds with `I will remind you “test” at 11:30AM every 4 weeks (next occurrence is today).` and after the 11:30AM reminder has passed, now says `(next occurrence is Friday, June 26th)`. I suspect the `next occurrence` text just refers to the initial start date specified when setting up the reminder.

Comment: That's very helpful!